# Fragment in Pager Adapter loads very slow (delay couple of seconds than load data)

Tags: android, performance, parsing, android-asynctask

I have Pager Adapter that initialize Fragment list. Problem is that Fragment loading very slow. It has delay of couple seconds, than start do load data. 
I have parsed data from URL in AsyncTask doInBackground() and worked with UI in AsyncTask onPosteExecute()

Here is my Fragment:

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)    {
    readBundle(getArguments());
    v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);

    new asyncTekstovi().execute(result);

    return v;
}

 public class asyncTekstovi extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> {

    String result;

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try {
            result = Ion.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                    .load(FragmentNewsReader.this.result)
                    .asString()
                    .get();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String  pasusUTekstu="";
        if (result != null){

            String htmlStringTekst=result.substring(result.indexOf("<!-- BEGIN .shortcode-content -->"), result.length());

            int startPositionTekst=htmlStringTekst.indexOf("<div class=\"shortcode-content\">");
            int endPositionTekst=startPositionTekst+"<div class=\"shortcode-content\">".length();

            while(htmlStringTekst.substring(startPositionTekst,endPositionTekst).indexOf("<!-- END .shortcode-content -->")<0){
                endPositionTekst++;
            }

            htmlStringTekst=htmlStringTekst.substring(startPositionTekst,endPositionTekst);
            //System.out.println("vladica:"+htmlStringTekst.length()+htmlStringTekst);
            int poc1;
            int kraj1;
            while((poc1=htmlStringTekst.indexOf("<div id"))>=0){
                //System.out.println("poc1="+poc1);
                kraj1=poc1+"<div id".length();
                while(htmlStringTekst.substring(poc1,kraj1).indexOf(">")<0){
                    //System.out.println("seckanje:"+htmlStringTekst.substring(poc1,kraj1));
                    kraj1++;
                }
                htmlStringTekst=htmlStringTekst.replace(htmlStringTekst.substring(poc1,kraj1),"<p>");
            }

            while((poc1=htmlStringTekst.indexOf("<p "))>=0){

                kraj1=poc1+"<p ".length();
                while(htmlStringTekst.substring(poc1,kraj1).indexOf(">")<0){

                    kraj1++;
                }
                htmlStringTekst=htmlStringTekst.replace(htmlStringTekst.substring(poc1,kraj1),"<p>");
            }
            htmlStringTekst=htmlStringTekst.replace("<div id","<p>");
            htmlStringTekst=htmlStringTekst.replace("</div>","</p>");
            htmlStringTekst=htmlStringTekst.replace("   ","");

            while(htmlStringTekst.length()>0){

                startPositionTekst=htmlStringTekst.indexOf("<p>");
                if(startPositionTekst>=0){


                    startPositionTekst+="<p>".length();
                    endPositionTekst=startPositionTekst;

                        while (htmlStringTekst.substring(startPositionTekst, endPositionTekst).indexOf("</p>") < 0) {
                            endPositionTekst++;
                        }

                        if(pasusUTekstu.indexOf("<img")<0) {
                            if(pasusUTekstu.length()>5) pasusUTekstu+="\n\n";
                            pasusUTekstu += htmlStringTekst.substring(startPositionTekst, endPositionTekst);   //e sad ja...

                        }
                        else {
                            pasusUTekstu=htmlStringTekst.substring(startPositionTekst,endPositionTekst);
                        }

                        htmlStringTekst = htmlStringTekst.substring(endPositionTekst);

                        pasusUTekstu = pasusUTekstu.replace("<strong>", "");
                        pasusUTekstu = pasusUTekstu.replace("</strong>", "");

                    int poc=pasusUTekstu.indexOf("<img");
                    int zastavica=0;
                    if(poc>=0) zastavica=1;
                    while(poc>=0) {
                        int kraj = poc;
                        while (pasusUTekstu.substring(poc, kraj).indexOf("/>") < 0) {
                            kraj++;
                        }
                        String link = pasusUTekstu.substring(poc, kraj);
                        pasusUTekstu = pasusUTekstu.replace(link, "");

                        poc = pasusUTekstu.indexOf("<img");
                    }

                    poc=pasusUTekstu.indexOf("<a href=");
                    while(poc>=0) {
                        int kraj = poc;
                        while (pasusUTekstu.substring(poc, kraj).indexOf(">") < 0) {
                            kraj++;
                        }
                        String link = pasusUTekstu.substring(poc, kraj);
                        pasusUTekstu = pasusUTekstu.replace(link, "");

                        poc = pasusUTekstu.indexOf("<a href=");
                    }

                    pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("&#038;","&");
                    pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("&#8211;","-");
                    pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("&#8220;","\"");
                    pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("&#8221;","\"");
                    pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("<p>","");
                    pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("</a>","");
                    pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("<br />","");
                    pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("</p>","");
                    pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("&nbsp;","");

                    pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("\n\n\n","\n");
                    //pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.replace("\n\n","\n");
                    //System.out.println("pocetak je:"+ pasusUTekstu);
                    if(zastavica==1) {
                        if(pasusUTekstu.substring(pasusUTekstu.length()-2).equals("\n\n")) pasusUTekstu=pasusUTekstu.substring(0,pasusUTekstu.length()-2);
                        listaTeksta.add(pasusUTekstu);
                        pasusUTekstu="";
                        zastavica=0;
                    }
                }
                else break;
            }
        }

        if(pasusUTekstu.length()>5) listaTeksta.add(pasusUTekstu);
        return listaTeksta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

        String rezultat = "";

        for(int i=0;i<listaSlika.size() ;i++) {
            v.findViewById(mLayoutIdArray[i]).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++) {
                textTv[i] = (TextView) v.findViewById(nizTekstaID[i]);
                textTv[i].setText(result.get(i));
        }
    }
    protected void onPreExecute()  {
    }
}
```

Here is my XML:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/vestGlavnaSlikaLayout"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:elevation="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/glavnaSlika"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layouttekstglavnevesti1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"


                android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/naslovglavni"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textSize="36sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lazoutZaNaslove"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/h"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/h"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/prednaslov"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-40dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/naslov1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/podnaslov"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <include
            layout="@layout/activity_slikatext1"
            android:id="@+id/includedLayout"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/h"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/h"
            android:layout_below="@id/lazoutSlikaTekst" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/activity_slikatext2"
            android:id="@+id/includedLayout1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/h"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/h"
            android:layout_below="@id/includedLayout" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/activity_slikatext3"
            android:id="@+id/includedLayout2"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/h"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/h"
            android:layout_below="@id/includedLayout1" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/activity_slikatext4"
            android:id="@+id/includedLayout3"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/h"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/h"
            android:layout_below="@id/includedLayout2" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/activity_slikatext5"
            android:id="@+id/includedLayout4"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/h"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/h"
            android:layout_below="@id/includedLayout3" />
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `readBundle()`?

Comment: It just get url to string from bundle :
    private void readBundle(Bundle bundle) {
        if (bundle != null) {
            result = bundle.getString("name");
        }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code to onViewCreated() method

```
new asyncTekstovi().execute(result);
```

Comment: Well its much better. Thx for answer.

Comment: Can you accept it as the answer if you're okay with this solution!